# Java Regex should match the substring but not make part of the result

Tags: java, regex

I'm unable to write a regex which match if any substring exist but not make it part of the result.

For eg:

```
3/4 length sleeve
3/4 length sleeves
3/4th length sleeve
3/4 sleeve
3/4 sleeves
3/4th sleeve 
3/4th sleeves
```

for all the above string it should match but finally return "3/4 sleeve" in the result.

I tried using lookahead but after reading http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html i came to know why it'll not work.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: What is the language?
I think after receiving the full string you can remove "length", "s" from end, "th "

Comment: @hwnd `3/4 sleeve(?=s)? match both '3/4 sleeve' and '3/4 sleeves'. It returns '3/4 sleeve' in result. But when I add the same logic for 'th', say `3/4(?=th)? sleeve(?=s)?`, the string doesn't match '3/4th sleeve'.

Comment: It won't you can't use lookahead like that. What language are you using?

Comment: @masum7 In Java. Yeah I can, but eventually the regex will be extended to consider other types like 'sleeveless' & 'sleeve less', one shoulder & 1 shoulder etc. Removing the string later require different rule for different string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not able to use **Positive Lookahead** the way you are trying to, instead you can place [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) around what you want to match then concatenate the match groups together to get your match results.

```
String s  = "3/4 length sleeve\n" +
            "3/4 length sleeves\n" +
            "3/4th length sleeve\n" +
            "3/4 sleeve\n" +
            "3/4 sleeves\n"+
            "3/4th sleeve\n" +
            "3/4th sleeves\n" +
            "long sleeves\n" +
            "longfoobarsleeve" +
            "shortnjjgfjghfdjghsleeves\n" +
            "shorts sleeveeees\n" +
            "short sleeve";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(3/4|long|short).*?(sleeve)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2));
}
```

Output

```
3/4 sleeve
3/4 sleeve
3/4 sleeve
3/4 sleeve
3/4 sleeve
3/4 sleeve
3/4 sleeve
long sleeve
long sleeve
short sleeve
short sleeve
short sleeve
```

Comment: Yeah this can work. Actually I have to add other cases in regex say 'long sleeve/longsleeve/long sleeves' should return long sleeve. Same for short sleeve, sleeveless etc. Trying to fix everything in 2 groups would be difficult later. Can't there be any solution which does it like lookahead.

Comment: Lookahead asserts that something else follows something for example, so the way you are trying to use it here, no. You can always group your first words together `(3/4|long|short).*?(sleeve)`

Comment: Thanks @hwnd. One last thing, how can I handle **sleeveless** (and strapless) in it. I'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: Just add them to a group like I shown you.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=(?:(3\/4)(?:th)?\s*(sleeve)s?)|(?:(3\/4)(?:th)?\s*length\s*(sleeve)s?)).*
```

Try this.This matches all and returns what you want.Replacement will be

```
$1 $2$3 $4
```

Just strip them of spaces at the end.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lU7jH1/3